# Multiple collision in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision

I am trying to make unblock me game. I have array of objects and I made boundaries collision. But now I am stuck with collision between objects. I made cycle over objects in array but it stops on the last one. How can I make collision check on each object everytime I move with my selected object?
Full code here: http://foxfcb.sweb.cz/ I am newbie in programming so please be patient.

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {

    ...

        var shapes = myState.shapes;
        var l = shapes.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {

            var shape = myState.shapes[i];
            var selection = myState.selection;

            // collision between objects
            if (selection.x < (shape.x + shape.w) && (selection.x + selection.w) > shape.x &&
                selection.y < (shape.y + shape.h) && (selection.y + selection.h) > shape.y) {
                myState.valid = true; //stop
            }
            // boundaries collision
            else if (myState.selection.x < 0 || myState.selection.y < 0 || myState.selection.x + myState.selection.w > 600 || myState.selection.y + myState.selection.h > 600) {
                myState.valid = true; //stop
            }

            else {
                myState.valid = false;  //moving

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting the `valid` flag when you check other objects.

So here is your collision detection as a function. Notice I set `state = false` once before the loop and if there is a collision I `break` out of the loop as there is no point detecting other collisions as the flag is either `true` or `false`. You were setting the flag back to `false` on all but the last object if you detected a collision.

```
var textCollision = function(){
    var shapes, l, shape, selection, i;
    shapes = myState.shapes;
    l = shapes.length;
    myState.valid = false; // assume no collision 
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        shape = myState.shapes[i];
        selection = myState.selection;
        if (selection.x < (shape.x + shape.w) && (selection.x + selection.w) > shape.x &&
            selection.y < (shape.y + shape.h) && (selection.y + selection.h) > shape.y) {
            myState.valid = true; //stop
            // there is no point testing any others as it will make no dif
            break; // step out of the for loop.
        }
        // boundaries collision
        else if (myState.selection.x < 0 || myState.selection.y < 0 || myState.selection.x + myState.selection.w > 600 || myState.selection.y + myState.selection.h > 600) {
            myState.valid = true; //stop
            // there is no point testing any others as it will make no dif
            break; // step out of the for loop.
        }
    }

}
```

**Break.**

Break is a javascript reserved token and is used to break out of loops and switches.

For loop

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    if(i === 2){
        break;  // exit the loop at 2
    }
}
```

While loop

```
while(i < 10){
    if(i === 2){
        break; // exit out of the while loop
    }
}
```

Also does the same on `do{ }While()` loops.

Break only exits the current loop;

```
for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){  // j loop
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){ // i loop
        if(i === 2){
            break;  // exit the i loop at 2
        }
    }
    // the break moves execution to the first line after the loop it is in 
    // the j loop continues as normal
}
```

Break is also used in switch statements

```
function num(i){
    switch(i){
    case 1:
       console.log("one");
       // no break token so execution continues inside the switch
    case 2:
       console.log("two");
    }
}
num(1); // outputs "one" "two"
```

To prevent this use `break`

```
function num(i){
    switch(i){
    case 1:
       console.log("one");
       break;  // break out of the switch

    case 2:
       console.log("two");
       // no point having a break here as it is at the end anyways
    }
    // break moves execution to here
}
num(1); // outputs "one"
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't write sooner. It's great idea with break but there is another mistake. In array there is included object with I am actually moving. And therefor It goes through condition and stop moving right at the begining. I need to extract object with I am actually moving from the array. But I think I can do it. Thanks alot. Really appriciate your help.

Comment: Ok I made condition for my array and It's working! :)
if (shapes[i] !== myState.selection) {
  ...
}